# How to pass dynamic value in .apned in reactjs

Tags: java, html, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I m using file upload with react and axios and fileupload working fine. and currently i am using fixed id in **data.append('customeId', '123456');** but i want to use id value dynamic bcz there are multiple user. i want to use this id like **let customeId = localStorage.getItem("customeId");**. please help me use id value dynamic.

**i am currently using**

```
uploadFile = ({ target: { files } }) =>{
    console.log( files[0] )
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('customeId', '123456');
    data.append( 'file', files[0] )
    // data.append = localStorage.getItem("brokerId");
    const options = {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        const {loaded, total} = progressEvent;
        let percent = Math.floor( (loaded * 100) / total )
        console.log( `${loaded}kb of ${total}kb | ${percent}%` );

        if( percent < 100 ){
          this.setState({ uploadPercentage: percent })
        }
      }
    }    
    axios.post("https://apimarkp.com/user/", data, options).then(res => { }
```

**What i want**

```
uploadFile = ({ target: { files } }) =>{
    let customeId = localStorage.getItem("customeId");
    console.log( files[0] )
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('customeId', 'customeId');
    data.append( 'file', files[0] )
    // data.append = localStorage.getItem("brokerId");
    const options = {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        const {loaded, total} = progressEvent;
        let percent = Math.floor( (loaded * 100) / total )
        console.log( `${loaded}kb of ${total}kb | ${percent}%` );

        if( percent < 100 ){
          this.setState({ uploadPercentage: percent })
        }
      }
    }    
    axios.post("https://apimarkp.com/user/", data, options).then(res => { }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you log in at the APP you should write on the localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("customeId", customer.Id);
```

now you can use in your function:

```
uploadFile = ({ target: { files } }) =>{
    let customeId = localStorage.getItem("customeId");
```

Comment: yes i alredy do it. but now i want to use in upload file